# SQL respect order rows in IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
pk int,
fk int,
col text,
sort_index int
)
```

and I have a query like this:

```
select b.fk from A where A.col in ('a','b', 'c')
group by b.fk
```

but I want only the `b.fk` that contains all elements in `IN` clause in order (using the column `sort_index`).

Is this possible with SQL? If so, how? (Oracle)

For example, I have this data

```
pk      fk    col    sort_index
1       1     a      1
2       1     c      2
3       1     b      3
4       2     a      1
5       2     b      2
6       2     c      3
```

I want just the fk 2 because it havs all col in IN and respect the order.

Comment: Do not use `IN` for this: it is incapable of representing this query. It can be done in n-JOINS, where n is the number of elements in the sequence. (And perhaps using a nifty "recursive" or "connect by" approach, but I'm an SQL Server guy ;-)

Comment: Lists within the `IN` ***do not*** have an order. You need to create a table instead; with the value in one column and the sort_index in the other. Then approach it with JOINs, and using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to check that all the items are present.

Comment: You need to give more detail. You say "fk 2" is acceptable because they have the col values in the correct order. Would it be ok if a was at sort_index 2, b at 3, and c at 4? Would it be ok if there was another letter between a and b so long as a comes before b and b comes before c?

Answer (score 0):

In case you can modify the IN values before executing the query , then this query may work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A1.FK
FROM A A1
WHERE A1.COL IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
and (SELECT WM_CONCAT(A2.COL)
    FROM A A2
    WHERE A2.FK = A1.FK) = 'a,b,c'
```

For this you will have to pass the IN values as comma separated quoted values('a', 'b', 'c') and only comma separated values (a,b,c).

Hope it helps